# Como tornar um campo unique para cada foreign key?

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou estudando mysql e me deparei com a seguinte situação e gostaria de saber se há uma solução estruturando minhas tabelas para resolver isso. Supondo que eu tenha duas tabelas; usuario (id, usuario, senha) e anotacoes(id, titulo, texto, id_usuario). Na tabela anotacoes 'id_usuario' é uma foreign key. Eu gostaria que o conteúdo do campo 'titulo' da tabela 'anotacoes' fosse único para cada foreign key. 
Obrigado desde já!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se for via comando basta utilizar este comando para adicionar uma *constraint* de unique composta:

```
ALTER TABLE Persons
    ADD CONSTRAINT UC_Person UNIQUE (ID,LastName);
```

Se for via `SGBD` basta editar a tabela, selecionar os campos e marcar a opção `Única` (`Unique`).